# datagridview selected column each row spelling check in vs2005 vb .net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows, datagridview

[How can i accesses the controls of this form from my application.
 my code is working but i am not able to stop it in between checking cell.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odj4C.png)

{

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

```
    Dim emptyItem As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim oNothing As Object = Nothing
    Dim oTrue As Object = True
    Dim oFalse As Object = False
    Dim Loopbreak As Object = False

    Dim oAlwaysSuggest As Object = True
    Dim oIgnoreUpperCase As Object = False
    Dim SpellingErrors As Integer = 0
    Dim ErrorCountMessage As String = String.Empty
    Dim WordApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application = _
       New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application()
    WordApp.Visible = False
    Dim ActualValue As String = ""

    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
    For rowCnt As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1


        Dim pProcess() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("winword")
        If Loopbreak = False Then
            For Each p As Process In pProcess

                If p.HasExited Then
                    p.Kill()
                End If

            Next
        WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
        WordDoc.Words.First.InsertBefore(DataGridView1.Rows(rowCnt).Cells(cmbSortColumns.SelectedValue).Value)
        Dim docErrors As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ProofreadingErrors = WordDoc.SpellingErrors
        SpellingErrors = docErrors.Count

        If SpellingErrors > 0 Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(rowCnt).Selected = True
                WordDoc.CheckSpelling(oNothing, oIgnoreUpperCase, oAlwaysSuggest, oNothing, oNothing, oNothing, oNothing, oNothing, oNothing, oNothing, oNothing, oNothing)
                ' format a string to contain a report of the errors detected
            ErrorCountMessage = "Spell check complete; errors detected: " + SpellingErrors.ToString()


            Dim first As Object = 0
            Dim last As Object = WordDoc.Characters.Count - 1
            ActualValue = DataGridView1.Rows(rowCnt).Cells(cmbSortColumns.SelectedValue).Value
            DataGridView1.Rows(rowCnt).Cells(cmbSortColumns.SelectedValue).Value = WordDoc.Range(first, last).Text


            If ActualValue = DataGridView1.Rows(rowCnt).Cells(cmbSortColumns.SelectedValue).Value Then
                DataGridView1.Rows(rowCnt).Cells(cmbSortColumns.SelectedValue).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
                Loopbreak = True
            End If

            End If



            WordDoc.Activate()
            DataGridView1.Rows(rowCnt).Cells(cmbSortColumns.SelectedValue).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red

        Else

        End If

        SpellingErrors = 0
    Next


    WordApp.Quit(oFalse, emptyItem, emptyItem)


    MsgBox("Spell Check Completed")




End Sub
```

}

Answer (score 0):

' format a string to contain a report of the errors detected

is not in code

[
  Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

```
    Dim emptyItem As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim oNothing As Object = Nothing
    Dim oTrue As Object = True
    Dim oFalse As Object = False
    Dim Loopbreak As Object = False

    Dim oAlwaysSuggest As Object = True
    Dim oIgnoreUpperCase As Object = False
    Dim SpellingErrors As Integer = 0
    Dim ErrorCountMessage As String = String.Empty
    Dim WordApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application = _
       New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application()
    WordApp.Visible = False
    Dim ActualValue As String = ""

    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
    For rowCnt As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1


        Dim pProcess() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("winword")
        If Loopbreak = False Then
            For Each p As Process In pProcess

                If p.HasExited Then
                    p.Kill()
                End If

            Next
        WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
        WordDoc.Words.First.InsertBefore(DataGridView1.Rows(rowCnt).Cells(cmbSortColumns.SelectedValue).Value)
        Dim docErrors As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ProofreadingErrors = WordDoc.SpellingErrors
        SpellingErrors = docErrors.Count

        If SpellingErrors > 0 Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(rowCnt).Selected = True
                WordDoc.CheckSpelling(oNothing, oIgnoreUpperCase, oAlwaysSuggest, oNothing, oNothing, oNothing, oNothing, oNothing, oNothing, oNothing, oNothing, oNothing)

            ErrorCountMessage = "Spell check complete; errors detected: " + SpellingErrors.ToString()


            Dim first As Object = 0
            Dim last As Object = WordDoc.Characters.Count - 1
            ActualValue = DataGridView1.Rows(rowCnt).Cells(cmbSortColumns.SelectedValue).Value
            DataGridView1.Rows(rowCnt).Cells(cmbSortColumns.SelectedValue).Value = WordDoc.Range(first, last).Text


            If ActualValue = DataGridView1.Rows(rowCnt).Cells(cmbSortColumns.SelectedValue).Value Then
                DataGridView1.Rows(rowCnt).Cells(cmbSortColumns.SelectedValue).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
                Loopbreak = True
            End If

            End If



            WordDoc.Activate()
            DataGridView1.Rows(rowCnt).Cells(cmbSortColumns.SelectedValue).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red

        Else

        End If

        SpellingErrors = 0
    Next


    WordApp.Quit(oFalse, emptyItem, emptyItem)


    MsgBox("Spell Check Completed")




End Sub
```

End Class
]